# Basic usage of Nick Gammon's Regexp library

Tags: library

I am using the following code modified from the examples. I get the count of matches but the actual value is not displayed

```
#include <Regexp.h>

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    MatchState ms;
    char buf [100];
    char buf2 [100] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy wolf";
    ms.Target (buf2);
    unsigned int count = ms.MatchCount ("[aeiou]");

    Serial.print ("Found ");
    Serial.print (count);
    Serial.println (" matches.");
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
          Serial.print ("Capture number: ");
          Serial.println (j, DEC);
          Serial.print ("Text: '");
          Serial.print (ms.GetCapture (buf, j));
          Serial.println ("'");
    }
}
void loop(){}
```

Comment: Could you add the output you are getting, to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined any capture groups in your regexp.

The regexp `[aeiou]` will *match* any of those characters, but it won't *capture* them.  To capture you need to define a *capture group* which is a sequence of tokens surrounded by parenthesis.  For instance:

```
([aeiou])
```

In your test phrase "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy wolf" that should match 11 times and capture each match, resulting in captures of *e u i o o u o e e a o*.

The reason why matching and capturing are two completely different things is so you can do things like `[aeiou]([aeiou])` which would capture the second vowel in a two vowel sequence. In your example it would match the *ui* of *quick* and capture just the *i*.